# When using a spellcasting archetype, do you take the Basic Spellcasting feat multiple times or once?

Tags: feats, multi-classing, spellcasting, pathfinder-2e

The rules for Basic Spellcasting state:

> **Basic Spellcasting Feat**: Available at 4th level, these feats grant a 1st-level spell slot. At 6th level, they grant you a 2nd-level spell slot. At 8th level, they grant you a 3rd-level spell slot. Archetypes refer to these benefits as the “basic spellcasting benefits.”

If you take this feat at 4th level, do you have to take it again at 6th level in order to get the 2nd-level spell slot? Or do you just automatically get it and you are free to choose another feat at 6th level? (I don't know if it is even possible to take feats more than once.)

Furthermore, what if you want to delay your multiclassing, and you dont take Basic Spellcasting until level 6. Do you get a 1st-level or a 2nd-level spell slot? Or both?

This whole wording is very unclear to me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Each Feat (Basic, Expert, and Master) (Class) Spellcasting provides all its spell slots at the appropriate character levels.

You get the full benefit based on character level, regardless of when you take the Feat. In your example of taking the Feat at level 6, you would gain both the 1st and 2nd level spell slot.

Firstly, there is no other "level" in Pathfinder v2 that this could refer to. With their assimilation of Multiclassing and Archetypes into your character level, you only have one level that it could be referring to.

Second, you may only take the Feat once unless it says otherwise (it does not). For example, the Basic Bard Spellcasting Feat (page 222)

> You gain the basic spellcasting benefits (page 219). Each time you gain a spell slot of a new level from the bard archetype, add a common occult spell or another spell you learned or discovered to your repertoire, of the appropriate spell level.

Third, looking at the above quote, it assumes you gain new spell slots while having the Feat "Each time you gain a spell slot of a new level from the bard archetype..."

Comment: So, just to confirm, if you take Basic Spellcasting at character level 6, you get both a 1st and 2nd level spell slot at the same time?

Comment: Also ugh I should have read the feat just under where I was reading: `ADVANCED MUSE’S WHISPERS: "You can select this feat more than once. Each time
you select it, you gain another bard feat."` So they would specify if you could take it more than once.

Comment: Yeah, you jump to your current level's benefits. So taking this at level 8+, you would immediately gain all of the benefits. It's a little strange, but you can hand-wave it as your experienced adventurer more quickly understanding basic abilities, I guess.

Comment: One thing that makes this interpretation clearer is that you only get new feats every 4 levels, so it would be impossible to choose one at 4th and then choose it again at 6th if the interpretation in OP were how it worked.

Comment: @JohnClifford That's not right - you get Ancestry feats at level 1 and every 4 thereafter, General Feats at level 3 and every 4 thereafter, and Class Feats at every even level (plus one at level 1, but that one may depend on your sub-class choice). Plus Skill Feats depending on your class (generally every even level, but Rogue gets one every level). Class Feats are the relevant ones for multiclass.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise there were class feats every even level. Thanks for the correction.